# Работа с колесиком (событие мыши)

Tags: c#, winapi

Доброго времени суток.

Я пытаюсь симулировать работу мыши геймпадом. Уже и двигаю и щелкаю - все работает. А вот колесико не получается сделать. Покопался в гугле, на MSDN, написал примерно такой код:

```
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x800;
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
...

if (js.GetButtons()[4] > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scrolling [-120]");
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, -120, 0);
}
if (js.GetButtons()[5] > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scrolling [120]");
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 120, 0);
}
```

Но ничего не происходит. То есть строки выполняются, но ничего не прокручивается. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mouse_event function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx). Координаты правильно передаете?
Попробуйте

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, -WHEEL_DELTA, 0);
```

**UPD**
Другая функция: [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: попробовал, ноль эмоций( Может есть какие-то другие методы, кроме mouse_event?

Comment: SendInput все-таки заставил работать "колесико"! Правда код получился раза в 4 длиннее, но все работает, спасибо)